# Upload Source Code larger than 512 mb to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload source code written in PHP to AWS elastic Beanstalk that exceeds more than 512 MB. Is there any ways to do this?

I had read through few forums, and this is the example forums found.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=287324

Comment: The post said that the only way is to create your own EC2 to do it.  I don't quite understand what you're looking for.

Comment: I am looking for the ways to deploy using elastic beanstalk instead of create own EC2.

Comment: One way is to split your code so that static content like images are stored in S3.  That would likely require a bit of rework to your environment.   But if that's not possible then it is not possible to use Elastic Beanstalk.  It has a set limit and you can't change it.

Comment: It's not a good practice to keep all of your static files, media files, database and so in the source code. Elastic Beanstalk allows you to add database, S3 bucket for your static and media files to your environment so you don't exceed the limit.